# ViewGroup invalidation after offsetLeftAndRight

Tags: android, android-view

I want one of my `ViewGroup` to be movable. Let's say, I want to click on it and the content below it reveals. On second click it closes again. Kind of `sliding menu` behaviour.

Here are my classes:

Custom scroller:

```
public class MyScroller implements Runnable {
    private static final String TAG = "MY_SCROLLER";
    private static final int ANIMATION_DURATION = 500;
    private final Scroller mScroller;
    private View mScrollingView;

    private int lastX = 0;
    private static final Interpolator sInterpolator = new Interpolator() {
        public float getInterpolation(float t) {
            t -= 1.0f;
            return t * t * t * t * t + 1.0f;
        }
    };

    MyScroller(final View view) {
        mScroller = new android.widget.Scroller(view.getContext(), sInterpolator);
        mScrollingView = view;
    }

    public void start(int initialVelocity) {
        Log.d(TAG, "start() called");
        int initialX = mScrollingView.getScrollX();
        int maxX = mScrollingView.getWidth();
        mScroller.startScroll(0, 0, maxX, 0, ANIMATION_DURATION);
        lastX = initialX;
        mScrollingView.post(this);
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.d(TAG, "run() called");
        if (mScroller.isFinished()) {
            mScrollingView.invalidate();
            return;
        }

        boolean more = mScroller.computeScrollOffset();
        int x = mScroller.getCurrX();
        int diff = x - lastX;
        if (diff != 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "x = " + x);
            mScrollingView.offsetLeftAndRight(diff);
            mScrollingView.invalidate();
            lastX = x;
        } else {
            forceFinished();
        }

        if (more) {
            mScrollingView.postDelayed(this, 16);
        }
    }

    void forceFinished() {
        if (!mScroller.isFinished()) {
            mScroller.forceFinished(true);
            mScrollingView.invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

and usage:

```
    viewGroup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new MyScroller(v).start(0);
        }
    });
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new MyScroller(v).start(0);
        }
    });
```

For `Button` everything works fine - it smoothly moves.
But `ViewGroup`s that I tried leave a trail like on screenshot.
RelativeLayout with Button inside left a trail.
Standalone Button moved perfectly.
What am I missing here?

[image]